# Python Image masking and removing Background

Tags: python, image-processing, mask, masking

I have two images:  the temple and the mask (the heart). I want to mask the temple with the shape of the heart and leave out the black background. The result should be a heart shaped cutout from the temple with a white or transparent background.

[image: Background]

[image: White Heart]

Comment: This sounds like a job for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm just unsure how to go about it

Comment: @sam shift the white  heart to the left and multiply the two images, maybe you need to stack the binary image in x3 shape to be multiplied by colour image and normalize the heart by 255.

Comment: I'm looking for a general method that coul work with any simple shape and image

Comment: where is your code? What did you try? What did you find in Google? Do you know module `pillow` or `cv2` ?

Comment: general method is to check first in Google, next write some code, and come to Stackoverflow when code gives error message.

Comment: Yea I tried Cv2.  I used this (below) thread to get me almost all the way but it seems some code is missing.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813546/how-do-i-crop-an-image-based-on-custom-mask-in-python/65523478?noredirect=1#comment115845665_65523478

Comment: [What's the most simple way to crop a circle thumbnail from an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58543750/whats-the-most-simple-way-to-crop-a-circle-thumbnail-from-an-image) it shows `pillow` and `putalpha(mask)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pillow` and `putalpha` to add grayscale image (`L`) to RGB image as `alpha` channel - so it will have transparent background. But both images have to be the same size.

```
from PIL import Image

# load images
img_org  = Image.open('temple.jpg')
img_mask = Image.open('heart.jpg')

# convert images
#img_org  = img_org.convert('RGB') # or 'RGBA'
img_mask = img_mask.convert('L')    # grayscale

# the same size
img_org  = img_org.resize((400,400))
img_mask = img_mask.resize((400,400))

# add alpha channel    
img_org.putalpha(img_mask)

# save as png which keeps alpha channel 
img_org.save('output-pillow.png')
```

[image]

---

**BTW:**

You can use other functions in `pillow` to resize only mask and keep original proportions of heart.

Black color give full transparent, white color keep original color, but you can also gray colors to make pixel half-transparent.

---

**EDIT:**

The same with `cv2`

```
import cv2

# load images
img_org  = cv2.imread('temple.jpg')
img_mask = cv2.imread('heart.jpg')

# convert colors
#img_org  = cv2.cvtColor(img_org, ???)
img_mask = cv2.cvtColor(img_mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# the same size
img_org  = cv2.resize(img_org,  (400,400))
img_mask = cv2.resize(img_mask, (400,400))

# add alpha channel 
b, g, r = cv2.split(img_org)
img_output = cv2.merge([b, g, r, img_mask], 4)

# write as png which keeps alpha channel 
cv2.imwrite('output-cv2.png', img_output)
```

**BTW:** `cv2` uses `BGR` instead og `RGB`